# Mouse positions in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have to show an alert message when the cursor only reaches the top of the browser(navigate to tabs) but not while moving to thee task bar and scrollbars. I tried with `pageX` and `pageY` but the values are different in Internet Explorer Kindly help me with the issue.

```
$('html').mouseleave(function(e) {
   if((e.pageY <= 5+$(window).scrollTop() && e.pageX >= ($(window).width() * 0/100 ))){
        alert("hai");
   }
)
```

this shows alert in firefox and chrome but not in ie

Comment: you can only base the values on the document reliably. There isn't a reliable way to detect actual hover of window tabs.

Comment: Can we see this mystery code?

Comment: $('html').mouseleave(function(e) {if((e.pageY <= 5+$(window).scrollTop() && e.pageX >= ($(window).width() * 0/100 )))   
{alert("hai");}) this shows alert in firefox and chrome but not in ie

Answer (score 0):

try with jQuery

```
var currentMousePos = { x: -1, y: -1 };
$(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    currentMousePos.x = event.pageX;
    currentMousePos.y = event.pageY;
});
```

with this you can get position of mouse on client

Comment: I don't have IE to test but does it _really_ return negative mouse positions? As far as I know they are always positive as negative means off screen and does not exist for the browser...

Comment: I have tested on chrome and firefox and it works, ie I used this code , let me know if it goes on IE , I think due to the cross- browsing functions of jquery .
For negative values ​​set to I - 1 data for matter of convenience , or that delivery by - 1px diagonal in the left - high monitor